# Import RealmRecyclerViewAdapter throught mavenCentral() instead of jcenter()

Tags: android, gradle, realm, jcenter, maven-central

This is a pretty straightforward question I would like to use the `RealmRecyclerViewAdapter` library on my project, but when I try to import it using `mavenCentral()` on my dependencies I got this error:

```
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugAarMetadata'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
   > Could not find io.realm:android-adapters:3.1.0.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/io/realm/android-adapters/3.1.0/android-adapters-3.1.0.pom
       - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/io/realm/android-adapters/3.1.0/android-adapters-3.1.0.pom
     Required by:
         project :app
```

However if I just use `jcenter()` it works fine.

I'm changing it here at my module gradle file:

```
repositories{
    jcenter()
    //mavenCentral()
}
```

**Is there any way to import this using mavenCentral() ?**

Answer (score 1):

I have a method which can help you get this library through `jitpack.io` repository.
First, add the repository in the `repositories {}` block like this:

```
repositories {
 ... 
 maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
}
```

Then add the dependency like this:

```
dependencies {
 implementation 'com.github.realm:realm-android-adapters:v3.1.0'
}
```

Comment: This worked for me.